# Could Soyuz spacecraft have saved the Columbia crew?

Tags: spacesuits, failure, soyuz-spacecraft, shuttle-columbia, rescue-missions

For the sake of the question, let's assume the STS-107 crew realizes in orbit that the heat shield is too damaged for reentry, but they realize it too late for shuttle Atlantis to rescue them in time. As reentry would most certainly mean death to the crew, the U.S. government asks Russia to send spacecraft into Columbia's orbit to save the crew. The Soyuz can fly unmanned controlled remotely as Soyuz 2 did, right?

So here go(es) my question(s):

- Could a Soyuz have reached Columbia's orbit (having an inclination of 39°) without wasting too much fuel in the first place? If the answer to this question is no, let's assume the Soyuz launched from Kourou, even though they didn't at that time.
- Once the Soyuz reaches the Columbia, would it be possible for the crew to open the Soyuz reentry module's hatch in their EVA suits? If not, could they possibly have been able to enter through the docking hatch of the orbital module?
- If only one Soyuz spacecraft was launched, three astronauts would have seats in the Soyuz' reentry module. What would the other four astronauts do when the Soyuz is about to reenter, experiencing up to 5g? Could they have fastened themselves somewhere in the capsule? If not, could they lie down or kneel and hold onto something?
- Would seven astronauts even fit into the reentry module? (even if they're quite squeezed together, since staying in the Columbia would mean death) And could more seats be possibly built into a Soyuz?
- Baikonur has at least one other launch pad used for Soyuz launches, and Kourou has multiple launch pads. So if Russia sent two Soyuz spacecraft instead of one, six astronauts would have seats. As for the seventh astronaut, the same questions as above apply, except that he/she would certainly fit with the other three into a Soyuz reentry module. What could he/she have done while the Soyuz is about to reenter at up to 5g?

Comment: There are a lot of questions here, suggest splitting them into at least two - one about getting the craft into orbit, and possibly the hatch, the second about re-entry with more than designed number of bodies inside as different people will have the expertise to answer different parts of this.

Comment: @GremlinWranger I'll think about it (SE doesn't allow to ask more than 1 question per hour, right?), but I don't really see a reason to split them as they go hand-in-hand and can be answered in one post. I mean, someone who has expertise on the space inside the Soyuz will most likely know whether a Soyuz can reach a 39°-inclination orbit and still have enough fuel to reenter).

Comment: The first issue is that preparing a Soyuz launch takes months. It would take a very lucky coincidence to have one, much less two on the launchpad almost ready to launch at the right moment.

Comment: There's no way all 7 would fit in one Soyuz capsule. Maybe 4, unlikely 5. Also, Russians would need to fly some Orlans up, which someone would need retrieve through EVA, 'cause 3 EVA suits on the Shuttle is def not enough, and moving into Soyuz in IVA suits (tethered to the shuttle by oxygen hose, which must then be crimped and cut when closing the hatch, astronauts passing out on oxygen remaining in the suit as Soyuz slowly re-pressurizes) is a little too sketchy to my liking. 
re: Reentry. Unbalanced like that it would need 6g+ ballistic reentry. Injuries guaranteed, lives saved.

Comment: @SF. Couldn't just one astronaut at a time go from the shuttle to the Soyuz, while another astronaut is taking the EVA suit of the astronaut in the Soyuz to bring it to another astronaut in the shuttle to get to the Soyuz?

Comment: @OldManJohn Maybe doable, although the problem is the EVA suit operate at 0.3bar, Soyuz and STS operate at 1bar, the process of adapting to the pressure change is lengthy. The whole operation would take ages and lots of air with the orbital module serving as an airlock, while people without suits are crammed like sardines in the reentry module. Unless there's a way to temporarily pump down Soyuz to 0.3 bar and re-pressurize it slowly with everyone inside.

Comment: Soyuz nominal reentry is about 4-5 g. With astronauts piled on top of each other things would not go well for the astronauts on the bottom. Besides their own body weighing 800 pounds they would have an 800 pound astronaut lying on top of them, which would lead to suffocation. Some type of support structure would need to be installed.

Comment: One important lesson that the results of the Columbia investigation made clear is that a rescue mission (by any spacecraft) has to be planned and ready prior to the launch of the operational mission. "Could they have saved Columbia if..." is pretty much a beaten down question by now. I think a more interesting question would be what modifications would be needed to make Soyuz a (planned) rescue vehicle for a seven person Shuttle crew. For example are two Soyuz sufficient or would it require three Soyuz.

Comment: @StevePemberton: I don't think that's quite true anymore. SpaceX can ready a Falcon 9 really quickly now. (But it was true at the time of Columbia.)

Comment: @Joshua ‐ Falcon 9 yes, Dragon capsule maybe not. And also working out a procedure on how exactly you are going to transfer astronauts between vehicles, considering that there might not be a safe way to run a zip line between the vehicles. And more importantly the Dragon capsule has to be depressurized the whole time this is going on, or at least whenever the hatch is open (unless the vehicles can dock). Too much to really discuss here in comments, I just think it's a complex thing to try and  quickly throw together only after an emergency has begun and with a timer counting down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you allow the possibility of launching from a launchpad that didn't exist at the time ([and the Soyuz pad in South America never had the infrastructure for crew launches anyway](https://www.space.com/14262-esa-manned-soyuz-launches-french-guiana.html)) - placing your question into "completely hypothetical" mode - the answer is no, as stated in the [CAIB report](https://history2.nasa.gov/columbia/CAIB.html). They didn't even consider rescue by expendable vehicle anyway, just launch of supplies.

> There has been some discussion regarding the possibility of
> sending supplies to Columbia using an expendable launch
> vehicle – to lengthen the amount of time available to execute a rescue mission. Because of Columbiaʼs 39-degree
> orbital inclination, an expendable launch from a launch site
> with a latitude greater than 39 degrees would not be able
> to reach Columbia. This rules out a Soyuz/Progress launch.
> There was an Ariane 4 in French Guiana that successfully
> launched an Intelsat satellite on February 15. The challenge
> with developing a supply kit, building an appropriate housing and separation system, and reprogramming the Ariane
> seems very difficult in three weeks, although this option is
> still in work.

CAIB report Volume 2 Appendix D.13

It would also have been impossible for Soyuzes from the ISS to reach Columbia. The inclination difference between the ISS and Columbia's orbits was about 12 degrees. At that altitude 1 degree of plane change takes about 120 m/s delta-v and [a Soyuz-TMA is capable of a total of about 390 m/s delta-v](http://wsn.spaceflight.esa.int/docs/Factsheets/35%20Soyuz%20LR.pdf).

Comment: Why is it so difficult to change the orbital inclination? Would it require insane amounts of fuel to change it from 46° (Baikonur's latitude) to 39°?

Comment: An additional problem with Ariane resupply in that timeframe is how would the  consumables be accessed by the Columbia crew? The Ariane upper stage presumably would have had a makeshift attachment for a supply container which could be accessed by astronauts on an (untethered) EVA. That might work for LiOH canisters, which was the immediate need, but there would be no way in that scenario to replenish the cryogenic oxygen and hydrogen, which if I understand correctly was right behind LiOH in terms of being a limiting consumable for Columbia beyond 30 days.

Comment: @StevePemberton I think this paragraph was included in the CAIB report just to cover "Frequently Asked Questions" not to indicate that anyone involved thought they were serious possibilities. "Resupply" was just asked about a lot by the general public.

Comment: @OldManJohn Yes it's very expensive in terms of propellant. As to "why" that's an orbital mechanics question and not in my wheelhouse, I just accept it as a given. There are hundreds of questions about inclination changes on this site.

Comment: @OldManJohn: Yes, inclination changes are expensive. Changing the inclination of a circular orbit by $\theta$ requires delta-v equal to $2\sin(\frac12\theta)$ times the orbital velocity. For $\theta = 7°$ that's about 12% of the total orbital velocity.

Comment: (For inclination changes of about 49° of more, it's actually more efficient to boost to a highly eccentric orbit, do the inclination change at apogee where velocity is negligible, and then circularize again at the new inclination. If you can aerobrake to circularize, the threshold drops to about 24°.)

Comment: For 10 degrees it's seems like it might be better to launch at a very steep south angle and correct after traveling 10 degrees south at a much lower velocity. It's still a boatload of fuel that a Soyuz doesn't have.

Comment: @Joshua, an extreme dogleg like that is still a very expensive maneuver.  You need to get up to a substantial fraction of orbital velocity just to get the 10-degree range.

Comment: If the goal is to abandon the shuttle anyway and not a resupply as in the report, you could try to meet half way and add whatever delta-v is left in the shuttle, e.g. whatever fuel is reserved for the deorbit burn. If you are willing to litter the orbit even further you could even think about dismantling the shuttle to decrease weight. Realistically this might still not be enough, but a group of astronauts in partially improvised space suits, strapped to a crudely detached aft part of the shuttle would definitely make an interesting scene for a science fiction movie.