# What is the lowest inclination orbit ever achieved by a crewed Soyuz mission?

Tags: history, soyuz-spacecraft, record, inclination

Inspired by a recent [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/65564/could-soyuz-spacecraft-have-saved-the-columbia-crew) regarding Soyuz capsules I wondered what is the lowest inclination Soyuz mission? Highest inclination human spaceflights have been asked about [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36290/6944) before. Soyuz 22 may have been the highest inclination Soyuz mission, but what is the lowest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears [Soyuz 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_1) had the lowest inclination of any Soyuz flight and any Soviet or Russian crewed orbital flight ever, at **50.8 degrees**. That's because most Soviet/Russian spaceflights went to a space station, all of which had a similar inclination as the ISS (~ 51.6°) and those that didn't had even higher inclinations, except Soyuz 1.